# python ssh connection problem

Tags: python, ssh

I tried this code:

```
 import paramiko
 ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
 ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
 ssh.connect('192.168.0.222', username='sshuser', password='pass')
 stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("pwd")    
 stdout.readlines()
```

and the ssh connection works, but as soon as I use:

```
 stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("pwd")
```

I get this error message:

```
  Exception in thread Thread-1 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown)
```

How can I just do the "pwd" command and get the output?
Thanks!

Comment: If you connect with ssh from a regular shell, verything works fine?

Comment: Yes. And when I just use the first 4 lines of code (the ssh connection part) everything works fine, too.
I'm using Python 2.6.

Comment: Are you connecting to a typical openssh server? What version of paramiko do you have? Can you provide the logs from paramiko, and possibly the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try:
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("pwd")
except SSHException:
    ssh.close()
```

That will keep it from crashing like that, but won't fix your problem. Make sure you can connect with a regular ssh client and run `pwd`. Then make sure your login credentials are correct.